# scp is still requesting password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I want to copy big files from one linux server(SLES11) to another(SunOS) via bash scripting. I dont want to have a password promt so I used ssh-keygen to generate key about this connection.These are the steps I followed:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
ssh-copy-id -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub swtrans@111.111.111.111
ssh -i id_rsa.pub swtrans@111.111.111.111
```

After this scp command still requests password.
I am not 'root' user in both servers.
I changed permissions to 700 to the .ssh directory and 640 to the file authorized_keys in the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -i id_rsa.pub swtrans@111.111.111.111
```

The `-i` argument accepts the private key, not the public one. You should use

```
ssh -i id_rsa swtrans@111.111.111.111
```

If it will not help, please provide the errors you can see in the server log and in the client